Convert asynchronous iterable to non-list iterable
The following code works as expected:
import asyncio
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable, Iterable


# In reality, this is more complicated.
async def create_asynchronous_iterable() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    for k in range(3):
        yield k


# In reality, this is more complicated.
def do_something(it: Iterable[int]) -> None:
    for k in it:
        print(k, end=" ")
    print()


async def main():
    async_it = create_asynchronous_iterable()
    it = [k async for k in async_it]
    do_something(it)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())  # Prints "0 1 2 ".

How can I turn it into an iterable that avoids waiting until all items are in memory, e.g. a generator?
I tried to replace the declaration of main as follows:
async def main():
    async_it = create_asynchronous_iterable()

    def create_iterable() -> Iterable[int]:
        async for k in async_it:
            yield k
    
    it = create_iterable()
    do_something(it)

However, this leads to:
SyntaxError: 'async for' outside async function

Is there a way to circumvent this limitation?

The naive replacement of it = [k async for k in async_it] by it = (k async for k in async_it) does not work since this turns it into an asynchronous iterable, not an iterable.

it is also in do_something btw! you meant main's it right?

Oh and I'm also curious why such non-async blocking loop is needed despite we're explicitly in async context, too. Maybe it could be an XY problem where you ask Y to achieve X, while X itself could be improved so that Y is not required.

why not just change do_something into async function, and then you can async for there??

This is harder than it first appears because do_something is not async, so it cannot suspend to the event loop. To do this, you can create a channel, fill it from your async code, and exhaust it from a generator - but you'd have to run do_something outside the event loop thread. See this answer for a similar approach that you could adapt.
